# Snapshotting a view that hasn't been rendered results in an empty snapshot

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

When camera is invoked I'm getting message:

```
Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot.
Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or 
snapshot after screen updates
```

I know it is due to privacy setting but Is there a way to tell user they have to change their Privacy Setting.

It doesn't trigger any of the function below..

```
Titanium.Media.showCamera({
    success:function(e){
        console.log('success');
    },
    cancel:function(){
        console.log('cancel');
    },
    error:function(error){   
        console.log('error code:', error.code);
    }
});
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this message before, however it may help to know that a view has an event trigger called `postlayout` which gets fired after the view has been rendered. You can try taking the snapshot after the view has triggered the `postlayout` event.